# Is there a way to collapse a few columns based on an index, while retaining the other columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like that :

| ID | Var1 | Var2 | Var3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | row1 | abc | 321 |
| 1 | row2 | bcd | 456 |
| 2 | row4 | def | 555 |
| 2 | row5 | tss | 889 |

And what I want to do is to join all the strings by a comma in Var1 according to ID, but retain all the other columns as is. So the last one should look like this:

| ID | Var1 | Var2 | Var3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | row1, row2 | abc | 321 |
| 1 | row1, row2 | bcd | 456 |
| 2 | row4, row5 | def | 555 |
| 2 | row4, row5 | tss | 889 |

I have tried aggregating, but if i do that, Var2 and Var3 is dropped. I have a few columns whose rows I want to join like I did with Var 1, is there a way to do this?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: did your query solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `groupby()`+`transform()`:

if order matters:

```
df['Var1']=df.groupby('ID')['Var1'].transform(lambda x:','.join(pd.unique(x)))
```

if order doesn't matters:

```
df['Var1']=df.groupby('ID')['Var1'].transform(lambda x:','.join(set(x)))
```

output of `df`:

```
    ID  Var1        Var2    Var3
0   1   row1,row2   abc     321
1   1   row1,row2   bcd     456
2   2   row4,row5   def     555
3   2   row4,row5   tss     889
```

Comment: Hi sorry, how do you ensure that only unique values are getting joined? So if row1 appears more than once, then it doesnt become "row1, row2, row1" but "row1, row2"

Comment: @JayneHow updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**